# Javascript and jquery working fine on jsfiddle but not locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my html, css and jquery working totally fine on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mwjqpqra/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>



    <title>World Wide Web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="java.js"></script>
    <div id="header">
        <div>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#index">Profect WWW</a>
            </div>
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#index">What</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#who">Who</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#how">How</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#when">When</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#awesome">Awesome!</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="adbox">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <img src="images/box.png" alt="Img" height="342" width="368">
            <div>
                <h1>WW What?</h1>
                <h2>Project World Wide Web.</h2>
                <p>
                    The World Wide Web (abbreviated as WWW or W3, commonly known as the Web) is a system of interlinked hypertext documents that are accessed via the Internet. With a web browser, one can view web pages that may contain text, images, videos, and other multimedia and navigate between them via hyperlinks. <span><a href="index.html" class="btn">Explore!</a><b>Don’t worry it’s for free</b></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contents">
        <div id="tagline" class="clearfix">
            <h1 id="whomade">Who made it ? O.o</h1>
            <section id="who">
            <div>
                <p>
                    Tim Berners-Lee, a British computer scientist and former CERN employee,and Belgian computer scientist Robert Cailliau are considered the inventors of the Web. 
                </p>
                <p>
                    On March 12, 1989, Berners-Lee wrote a proposal for what would eventually become the World Wide Web.</p>
                <p>
                    The 1989 proposal was meant for a more effective CERN communication system but Berners-Lee eventually realised the concept could be implemented throughout the world.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Berners-Lee and Belgian computer scientist Robert Cailliau proposed in 1990 to use hypertext "to link and access information of various kinds as a web of nodes in which the user can browse at will",and Berners-Lee finished the first website in December of that year.
                </p>
                <p>
                    The first test was completed around 20 December 1990 and Berners-Lee reported about the project on the newsgroup alt.hypertext on 7 August 1991.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Wix is an online website builder with a simple drag & drop interface, meaning you do the work online and instantly publish to the web.
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
        </div>
        <div id="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <input checked type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide1"/>
                <label for="Slide1" id="s1"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide2"/>
                <label for="Slide2" id="s2"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide3"/>
                <label for="Slide3" id="s3"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide4"/>
                <label for="Slide4" id="s4"></label>
            <div class="overflow-wrapper">
                <a class="slide" href=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hKju1EC.jpg"/></a>
                <a class="slide" href=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hKju1EC.jpg"/></a>
                <a class="slide" href=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hKju1EC.jpg"/></a>
                <a class="slide" href=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hKju1EC.jpg"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div id="connect">
                <a href="http://freewebsitetemplates.com/go/facebook/" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a><a href="http://freewebsitetemplates.com/go/googleplus/" target="_blank" class="googleplus"></a><a href="http://freewebsitetemplates.com/go/twitter/" target="_blank" class="twitter"></a><a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com/misc/contact/" target="_blank" class="tumbler"></a>
            </div>
            <p>
                © 2025 Dark Virtuality.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Java.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

But the webpage doesn't even seem to pick up the .js code and jquery and java.js don't work locally on my PC. I have already tried on different browsers such as chrome, firefox developer edition, and even IE but no luck

Comment: show console output or no error

Comment: `$document.ready` should be `$(document).ready` - this is the difference between your local version and jsfiddle where it's wrapping it in `onload` for you.

Comment: FYI, javascript is different than java

Comment: And BTW your jsfiddle links don't all work anyway.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thank you for your prompt reply. I tried it already but no luck

Comment: @Godisgood . Thank you for your reply. I am talking about the who link. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @A.Wolff . Sir, i am aware of that fact that they two are totally different but you see i am too lazy to type javascript when naming the file :P

Comment: I am really sorry that i ignored the fact that i have typed Java in the heading of the question. How foolish can i be.

Comment: press f12 and tell us the error log please...we do not have access to the code running on your local machine

Comment: If you've already tried `$(document).ready`, perhaps edit it into the code in the question so it's up to date, and also include any errors / console output as per @johnSmith's comment.

Comment: @LoganMurphy I beleive i have no javascript or css errors as the window is blank. Please tell me f i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is clearly with

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Because you are running it locally, `//` does not link to where you want it to link. you need to manually either use `http:` or `https:`

So... use

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If it works on `JSFiddle` but not on your local host, then this is the problem.

I did not ready any of your code because I spotted this.

read more about it [here](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/#protocolless) if you would like

Comment: +1 Good spot.  I use [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) when working locally - helps to avoid things like this whilst developing.

Comment: @AdityaAgrawal an error like this wouldve appeared in the error log